# How to provide link on job on Github Action visualisation graph

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

One of the tasks that I've found called **actions/deploy-pages@4** provides direct url link to the github pages. That link is displayed on the visualisation graph which makes it easy to access without scrolling through the summary of action. I cannot find anything in the documentation about influencing the graph just simple explanation what is it:
[link to documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/using-the-visualization-graph)

There is any way to do in on my own? To provide any link that I need there? The screen presents what is my expectation:

[block of job with link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOvPh.png)

I tried to find the way on official documentation and on the internet but without any data about that.